# Session expiration warning and extend ASP.NET Web Application hosting HTML pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, session-state

We have an ASP.NET web application running on IIS implementing Forms Authentication. Once the user
authenticates, they enter a web of HTML pages (we have no control over these pages).
The requirement is that the user receives a "Session about to expire" message before 'x' minutes of the session timeout (IIS session timeout = 20 minutes)
and let them extend it if required.

I understand that when a request hits the IIS server, it automatically resets the 20 minutes timeout window.

What I have tried so far -

1. I tried creating a new module implementing IHTTPModule (since I cannot extend the SessionState module),
   to capture the last session access time, logout time and warning time (in AcquireRequestState).
   But, the once the request is authenticated - I loose the session data (issue #1)
   After the request is completed and the request (HTML) page is rendered - how do we display the message? (issue #2)

   (Issue #3)I cannot use client side scripting solutions as the HTML pages are not in our control.

I want to understand which method (not client side monitoring) runs in the application background
after a page is rendered that can keep monitoring the session timeout value and the last acess time.
Can you please help me find a suitable solution that can be implemented on IIS server side?

Comment: There are many approaches but none of them should start from server side. For example, Telerik has a browser side timer, https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/notification/examples/sessiontimeout/defaultcs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can't, since you don't know if the user is now shopping on Amazon, or closed their computer and went home for the day.

In other words, since the web is state-less, you don't know if the user has any pages open at all. They may have turned off their computer, and then 20 minutes later when session ends.

How then are you going to know that they even have any web pages open to your site? Answer: you can't and you don't know and you can't know.

The only way to thus achieve this goal is to adopt some type of "system" that allows the server to communicate with the browser. (but that's not what the web server normally does).

the web server can dish out a page to the client side. And once done, that page, the variables, the page class and everything else for that ONE web page is now disposed, and blowen out of existence.

The web server is just sitting there waiting for ANY user to post a page back to the server. However, the server has ZERO knowledge if the user closed their computer, or started shopping on amazon with their web browser.

So, EVEN if you were to say have a 10 second warning that session is about to expire, how you going to send ANY data or any information to the client side that now may well not exist?

And maybe the user has 10 copies of 10 different pages open from your web site - which one you going to send a message to???

You don't know if that web page is still open, and the server has no means to know this. You close your web browser, the server does not know that you have no web pages open for that existing site.

So, YES, this means you have to add/have/adopt some client side code. That means either SignalR, or your own custom code.

With SignalR, or some custom code, you now have a means for the server to send information to the browser. However, without some client side code to "make up" and keep such a connection, then you can't do this.

You can NOT in ANY case send requests to the client computer. (you don't even know if they have 5 of your web pages open in 5 tabs, or they have zero pages open.

However, If you adopt say some type of "system" that keeps, or creates, or maintains a connection to the server at all times, then yes, you can do this. Such a so called system would be for example SignalR.

But, be it some simple JavaScript code, or a library of code like signalR?

Other then some browser side code, you can't do this 100% server side.

You have to adopt some client side code. Now, if you have a master page that all pages use, then great, you not have to modify every web page then, but you WILL have to have some client side code to achieve this goal.